# How to create pm2 ecosystem.json file for node js express app which starts using npm start?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, pm2

I want to use pm2 for node js express app.
I am able to start node js server using npm start.
I want to configure the same in ecosystem.json file so that i can start by using pm2 tool.
Also i want to start in cluster mode.

Please note that i am able to start the node js app by using the command below

**pm2 start "/usr/bin/npm" --name "blaze-node" -- start -i 0**

There are two problems with the above command.

1. It is not configured in ecosystem.json file.
2. It is not obeying the -i 0 parameter. It only start single instance.

Some more information

Below is the ecosystem.json file

```
   {
   "apps":[
      {
         "name":"blaze-node",
         "script":"npm",
         "exec_mode":"cluster",
         "instances":"0",
         "env_dev":{
            "watch":true,
            "NODE_ENV":"dev"
         },
         "env_qa":{
            "watch":false,
            "NODE_ENV":"qa"
         },
         "env_prod":{
            "watch":false,
            "NODE_ENV":"prod"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

If i execute the below command
pm2 start ecosystem.json --env dev
it show the nice output showing that the processes have been started.
But nothing is getting listened on 3000 port.

Instead when i use the command without using ecosystem.json file
as below

**pm2 start "/usr/bin/npm" --name "blaze-node" -- start -i 0**

Every thing works fine except those two problems as stated above.

Please help.

Comment: I am able to start the app in cluster mode by using the below command

pm2 start "/usr/bin/npm" --name "blaze-node" -i 0 -- run start

Please note that above command still doesn't use the ecosytem.json file.

Comment: What do you get with "pm2 status" and "pm2 logs"?

Comment: " am able to start the app in cluster mode by using the below command pm2 start "/usr/bin/npm" --name "blaze-node" -i 0 -- run start Please note that above command still doesn't use the ecosytem.json file. –"

If you are not using ecosystem.json file, even then you need to run the pm2 start command from parent directory of the symlink.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a combination of `script`, `args`, and `node_args` within a **pm2** config.js to achieve this. It sounds counter-intuitive to have **pm2** *script entry point* call an npm *script entry point* to invoke a script! Better to bypass package.json at this point and achieve the same script execution using those 3 config parameters in combination.